# Understanding YAML

Tags: yaml

I am trying to understand very basic concept of YAML. I didn't find any relevant documentation which can clear my doubts. For example:

```
product:
    - sku         : BL394D
      quantity    : 4
      description : Basketball
      price       : 450.00
    - sku         : BL4438H
      quantity    : 1
      description : Super Hoop
      price       : 2392.00
tax  : 251.42
total: 4443.52
```

`product` is, I guess, a sequence with:

```
- sku         : BL394D
```

As data. I have read that in YAML you can define a sequence as:

```
name:
 -a
 -b
 -c
```

My question is that in `product` sequence what are these values? They do not have a hyphen in front of them as items of sequence has.

```
      quantity    : 4
      description : Basketball
      price       : 450.00
```

Do they also belong to sequence or are nested `key: value` pairs for `sku`? I am totally confused. Help me understand the very basic syntax with example of list, maps and nesting lists inside maps and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`product` is a sequence of two maps, each of them containing a `sku`, a `quantity`, a `description` and a `price` entry.

You can find some examples and description [here](https://github.com/Animosity/CraftIRC/wiki/Complete-idiot%27s-introduction-to-yaml).

Comment: How will you access description : Basketball. To access quantity in third line i can access the same as [product][quantity]

Answer (score 1):

as the key `quantity` is indented at the same level as `sku` is indented, they are keys for the same mapping (and so are `description` and `price`). This mapping is an sequence element introduced at one indentation level less than the keys are indented, by the `-`.

A probably more clear way to write this would be the equivalent to your example:

```
product:
    - 
      sku         : BL394D
      quantity    : 4
      description : Basketball
      price       : 450.00
    - 
      sku         : BL4438H
      quantity    : 1
      description : Super Hoop
      price       : 2392.00
tax  : 251.42
total: 4443.52
```

The way you can access the value for quantity depends of course on the language you work with (and possible what library you use). For ruamel.yaml and PyYAML under Python you can do:

```
data['product'][0]['quantity']
```

to get the value `4`

---

It often helps to look at (valid) YAML data in a different way, especially since the syntax has multiple forms, and it might not be obvious that

```
abc:
  - 1
  - 2
```

is a mapping from key `abc` to a single sequence with two values (`1` and `2`), and that this is equivalent:

```
abc:
- 1
- 2
```

and so is:

```
abc: [ 1, 2]
```

What often helps is looking at an [online YAML parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=product%3A%0A%20%20%20%20-%20sku%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20BL394D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20quantity%20%20%20%20%3A%204%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20description%20%3A%20Basketball%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20price%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20450.00%0A%20%20%20%20-%20sku%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20BL4438H%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20quantity%20%20%20%20%3A%201%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20description%20%3A%20Super%20Hoop%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20price%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%202392.00%0Atax%20%20%3A%20251.42%0Atotal%3A%204443.52&type=json) if you are more familiar with JSON notation than with YAML or use its [Python](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=product%3A%0A%20%20%20%20-%20sku%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20BL394D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20quantity%20%20%20%20%3A%204%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20description%20%3A%20Basketball%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20price%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20450.00%0A%20%20%20%20-%20sku%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20BL4438H%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20quantity%20%20%20%20%3A%201%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20description%20%3A%20Super%20Hoop%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20price%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%202392.00%0Atax%20%20%3A%20251.42%0Atotal%3A%204443.52&type=python) output.

You can also easily do this locally if you work with Python:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml as yaml
import json
from pprint import pprint

yaml_str = """\
product:
    - sku         : BL394D
      quantity    : 4
      description : Basketball
      price       : 450.00
    - sku         : BL4438H
      quantity    : 1
      description : Super Hoop
      price       : 2392.00
tax  : 251.42
total: 4443.52
"""

data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
pprint(data)
print('='*40)
json.dump(data, sys.stdout, indent=2)
```

which will give you:

```
{'product': [{'description': 'Basketball',
              'price': 450.0,
              'quantity': 4,
              'sku': 'BL394D'},
             {'description': 'Super Hoop',
              'price': 2392.0,
              'quantity': 1,
              'sku': 'BL4438H'}],
 'tax': 251.42,
 'total': 4443.52}
========================================
{
  "product": [
    {
      "sku": "BL394D", 
      "price": 450.0, 
      "description": "Basketball", 
      "quantity": 4
    }, 
    {
      "sku": "BL4438H", 
      "price": 2392.0, 
      "description": "Super Hoop", 
      "quantity": 1
    }
  ], 
  "total": 4443.52, 
  "tax": 251.42
}
```